# Is the range 951 to 1999 reserved for application level node ids in OPC UA address space?

Tags: opc, opc-ua

From looking at the [node ids file](https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/master/tools/schema/NodeIds.csv) , you'll notice that node ids skip the range 951 - 1999 i.e. there are no OPC UA nodes with nodeids within that range.

Is the range reserved for application use ? Is it safe for my server implementation to use nodeids in the range 950 - 1999 ?

I'm also seeking a part of the specification that mentions about the nodeid range.

Answer (score 6):

What you are referring to are node IDs in the namespace 0 (with URI being http://opcfoundation.org/UA/ ). The whole namespace is reserved for use by OPC Foundation. You are not allowed to define any new NodeIDs in this namespace - no matter what their numeric or other identifier.

For nodes specific to your server, you should define your own namespace - and then it's all yours. You can then use any node identifiers inside this namespace - even numeric ones "colliding" with namespace 0 (which, in fact, is no collision at all, as the namespaces are there for the purpose of preventing the collisions).

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer. Can you please share the part of the specification that mentions what you've just said ? I would need it for personal reference.

Comment: Interestingly, I cannot find a full coverage of this in the UA specs. It might still be there though. You may ask on https://opcfoundation.org/forum/ if you are seriously interested. The closest I could find (in version 1.03 of the OPC UA specs) is in Part 3, 8.2.2 NamespaceIndex where it defines the OPC UA namespace as being “http://opcfoundation.org/UA/” with an index in the namespace table being 0. I think the fact the namespace is an URI implies that only the owner of "opcfoundation.org" is entitled to define stuff "below" it, but cannot provide an evidence for that now.

Comment: Just found what i was looking for in the spec,  looking at Chapter 3 of the spec, page no. 59, section 8.2 (Nodeid) you'll see a clear description of how namespace uri's should be used to prevent collisions within the namespace.